# JS / jQuery Reorder data attribute for elements on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of elements like the following:

```
<div>    
  <div data-pos="1">Elem 1</div>
  <div data-pos="2">Elem 2</div>
  <div data-pos="3">Elem 3</div>
  <div data-pos="4">Elem 4</div>
  <div data-pos="5">Elem 5</div>
  <div data-pos="6">Elem 6</div>
  <div data-pos="7">Elem 7</div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking one the elements (e.g. Elem 4 in the example below) I want the data-pos attributes to be reordered like the following:

```
<div>    
  <div data-pos="5">Elem 1</div>
  <div data-pos="6">Elem 2</div>
  <div data-pos="7">Elem 3</div>
  <div data-pos="1">Elem 4</div>
  <div data-pos="2">Elem 5</div>
  <div data-pos="3">Elem 6</div>
  <div data-pos="4">Elem 7</div>
</div>
```

I'm sure there is a really simple way of doing this but I'm just not seeing it. I just deleted my code as it wasn't anywhere near to working, so have nothing to show you I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick (it is pure js, [jQuery is unnecessary here](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)).

```
function reOrder(firstDivI){
  divs.forEach(function(thisDiv, thisDivI){
    thisDiv.setAttribute("data-pos", (7 - firstDivI + thisDivI) % 7 + 1);
  });
}
```

Look at the snippet below to see it working.

```js
var divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-pos]"));

function reOrder(firstDivI){
  divs.forEach(function(thisDiv, thisDivI){
    thisDiv.setAttribute("data-pos", (7 - firstDivI + thisDivI) % 7 + 1);
  });
}

divs.forEach(function(div, divI){
  div.addEventListener("click", reOrder.bind(null, divI));
});
```

```css
[data-pos]::before{
  color: lightblue;
}
[data-pos="1"]::before{
  content: "1 ";
}
[data-pos="2"]::before{
  content: "2 "; 
}
[data-pos="3"]::before{
  content: "3 "; 
}
[data-pos="4"]::before{
  content: "4 "; 
}
[data-pos="5"]::before{
  content: "5 "; 
}
[data-pos="6"]::before{
  content: "6 "; 
}
[data-pos="7"]::before{
  content: "7 ";
}
```

```html
<div>    
  <div data-pos="1">Elem 1</div>
  <div data-pos="2">Elem 2</div>
  <div data-pos="3">Elem 3</div>
  <div data-pos="4">Elem 4</div>
  <div data-pos="5">Elem 5</div>
  <div data-pos="6">Elem 6</div>
  <div data-pos="7">Elem 7</div>
</div>
```